# blog detail template does not exist error

Tags: django, django-views

I have a simple blog app which has a blog list view and their detail pages that are generated automatically. everything seems to work just fine in local. however after I deployed the app on the server when I click to see the detail page I get a Template does not exist error.
this is my views:

```
class BlogMain(ListView):
    model = BlogPost
    template_name = 'Blog/Blog-news.html'
    queryset = BlogPost.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-published']
    paginate_by = 3

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogMain, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tags'] = BlogPost.tags.all()
        return context


class BlogTags(ListView):
    model = BlogPost
    template_name = 'Blog/Blog-news.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return BlogPost.objects.filter(tags__slug=self.kwargs.get('tag_slug'))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogTags, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tags'] = BlogPost.tags.all()
        return context


class BlogDetail(DetailView):
    model = BlogPost
    template_name = 'Blog/Blog-news-detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'blog'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'the_slug'
    slug_field = 'slug'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["related_items"] = self.object.tags.similar_objects()[:3]
        return context
```

this is my urls:

```
path('blog/', views.BlogMain.as_view(), name="blog-page"),
path('log/tags/<slug:tag_slug>/', views.MaghaleTags.as_view(), name="tagged"),
re_path(r'blog/(?P<the_slug>[-\w]+)/', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
```

and finally my templates:

```
{% for post in posts %}
<div class="container-fluid blog-main mb-5">
    <a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.slug %}">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 pt-5 pb-3 my-5">
                <h5>{{ post.title | persianize_digits }}</h5>
                <small>
                    {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
                    {{ tag.name }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </small>
                <br>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: is your template located in `appName > templates > appName > template.html`?

Comment: yes. I have another news page just like this one in this app and it works properly both local and on the server. when I add new posts, it gets created and added to the main view but the detail wont work

Answer (score 0):

I am sure is this the issue with you I'll just share my experience. I named my template **blog.html** and in the code I wrote **Blog.html** just starting character capital. It was running great with my local server but when I deployed the website on pythonanywhere.com it gave me the same error **template does not exist** so I changed the template name to **blog.html** in the code and it worked. See if you are having this kind of issue.